# NSOutlineView cell font color not respecting nib?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

If you take a look at this image:

[image: Text color]

My cell's text color is white. However, when I run the app I get this:

[image: Not white].

My `viewForTableColumn` is:

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    if ([self isHeader:item]) {
        return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
    } else {
        return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
    }
}
```

Which are just the identifiers for my header and data cell (not defined anywhere else other than in the nib).

What I am doing wrong? How come my header cell is coming out another color other than white?

Note: Table is view based NOT cell based.